# Reading webpack's .env files with grunt

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs

I'm using **grunt-replace** to perform some substitutions of variables according to the environment (dev/testing/production). Those variables are set like this:

```
config: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    variables: {
                        base_url: 'localhost'
                    }
                }
            },
            testing: {
                options: {
                    variables: {
                        base_url: 'testing.example.com'
                    }
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    variables: {
                        base_url: 'production.example.com'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Then I'm replacing the variables with **grunt-replace**, like this:

```
replace: {
            main: {
                options: {
                    patterns: [
                        {
                            match: 'BASE_URL',
                            replacement: '<%= grunt.config.get("base_url") %>'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                src: 'src/main.js' ,
                dest: 'dist/main.js'
            },
}
```

Since I'm using an `.env` file configured for the mentioned environments, is it possible to tell grunt-env to load that file and perform the replacements in replacement of **grunt-config**? I would like to do this in order to avoid having duplicated code for setting those variables in each environment along both webpack and grunt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your .env file using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme), and then pass it to grunt config.

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const envConfig = dotenv.config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' }).parsed;
```